# NavigationItem color changes when the Popover(UIPopoverPresentationController) comes down

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to iOS programming. I have a UIButton which on click shows a Popover.I also have a NavigationItem above the UIButton.I have observed that whenever the Popover comes down the NavigationItem area greys out...It looks like normal behaviour in iOS...But I need prevent this...Please help.
PFA screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hey, that is the default app behaviour.

Comment: @Vignesh I know...But I need to prevent that...is there a work around?

Comment: no workaround to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `UIView` and with the animation, you can display as you like without gray part